# Can i launch Android Browser with Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

I am new for Robotium. I am trying to launch Android Browser with Robotium. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getInstrumentation().getContext().startActivity(i);
```

However it will open another application and you will not be able to do anything else with robotium.

Answer (score 0):

```
Robotium can be used for accessing views inside the application. Since browser is another    application you cannot access it. 

Only you can just launch a browser using the following code

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
Context instrumentationContext=getInstrumentation().getContext();
instrumentationContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
```